# The images of two non homotopic to identity maps intersect

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

How could one prove that images two maps $f,g:\mathbb RP^4 \to \mathbb RP^7$ which are not homotopic to trivial map have nonempty intersection.